# Difference in an attribute value when asking object directly vs iterating over all table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, mysql2

I  have a weird anomaly with a specific object in my table.

**For ex**. let's say I have an `User` table which has an attribute `birthday`.

If I iterate over `User` table even without asking no attributes at all I get an error because of invalid entry:

```
1.9.3-p551 :022 >   begin
1.9.3-p551 :022 >     User.all.map {|u| u }
1.9.3-p551 :023?>   rescue => e
1.9.3-p551 :024?>     puts "Problem with user #{u.id}, error: #{e}"
1.9.3-p551 :025?>   end
  User Load (267.5ms)  SELECT `user`.* FROM `user`
Problem with user 2569, error: Invalid date in field 'birthday': 1998-07-00
 => nil
```

Now if I ask directly from the current problematic object what is its birthday, it will give me the correct value with correct data type:

```
1.9.3-p551 :027 > u = User.find(2569)
1.9.3-p551 :027 > u.birthday
 => Tue, 12 Oct 2000
```

Attribute defined in `schema`:

```
 create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.date      "birthday"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the variable scope: within the `map` block, the `u` is defined to current iterated object, but outside that block `u` is **undefined**.

*Then how come the error output can give out the `u.id`?* you might ask.

That is because you have `u` defined outside this whole block (perhaps some earlier testing).

Observe this code:

```
u = 1
puts "before: #{u}"
5.times{|u| puts u}
puts "after: #{u}"
```

Output:

```
before: 1
0
1
2
3
4
after: 1
```

Comment: Yep, I mistakenly assumed that doing `reload!` in console before defining the `begin-rescue` block will also forget all the variables too, which it didn't apparently.

Answer (score 1):

When you just call User.all.map {|u| u } the user gets the message inspect passed to it.  Inspect by default just returns a nicely formatted version of your object.  So because it has bad data for birthday that is why it errors.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inspect

Solution is to do a data migration to get all your birthdays in expected format.

Comment: I understand different formatting/data type, but I have a completely different value at birthday slot (1998-07-00 vs Tue, 12 Oct 2000) - where could it come from?

Comment: Rails should auto serialize datetimes for you.  Would have to have been added directly, bypassed serialize, or been a different column type at one time.  Just migrate it to proper format and all should be well.  Ie read it in and format like your other birthdays.

Comment: On side note, you could add a validation for date format in your model for birthday and that would prevent the problem from recurring.

Comment: Still I don't understand why should i receive such different values when I'm asking it while iterating over the whole table (`User.all`) vs asking object directly (`User.find`)

Comment: When you find it do a u.inspect

Comment: If I inspect it, I get the correct type value. I even saved a new birthday date from `Date` class for this user but still I get the same kind of difference when iterating over the table with `User.all` vs asking directly `User.find`.